How to automate license extraction for sub-packages when using license-webpack-plugin?
I am currently using the license-webpack-plugin, which works well to extract license information when the target repository has a LICENSE file. However, there is an issue when the target package is a sub-package and the parent package contains the LICENSE file. In such cases, the plugin fails to extract the license information (e.g., Mantine). Currently, I am handling this manually, but I am looking for a way to automate this process. Could you investigate whether there is another library or option that can automate this
